# Use Arabic Characters as Slug in Laravel

Tags: php, regex, laravel, seo, slug

I am using this package [Github : eluquent-sluggable-persian](https://github.com/morilog/eluquent-sluggable-persian) to use arabic language for slug, they use regular expression for the package Config File, I am not that good at it , the error i have is

> ErrorException in sluggable.php line 106: 
>   preg_replace(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 0

`sluggable.php` is the config file that i should replace with the original config file, I need to know how to fix that.

The Code with the error

```
'method' => function($string, $separator = '-')
{
    $_transliteration = array(
        '/ä|æ|ǽ/' => 'ae',
        '/ö|œ/' => 'oe',
        '/ü/' => 'ue',
        '/Ä/' => 'Ae',
        '/Ü/' => 'Ue',
        '/Ö/' => 'Oe',
        '/À|Á|Â|Ã|Å|Ǻ|Ā|Ă|Ą|Ǎ/' => 'A',
        '/à|á|â|ã|å|ǻ|ā|ă|ą|ǎ|ª/' => 'a',
        '/Ç|Ć|Ĉ|Ċ|Č/' => 'C',
        '/ç|ć|ĉ|ċ|č/' => 'c',
        '/Ð|Ď|Đ/' => 'D',
        '/ð|ď|đ/' => 'd',
        '/È|É|Ê|Ë|Ē|Ĕ|Ė|Ę|Ě/' => 'E',
        '/è|é|ê|ë|ē|ĕ|ė|ę|ě/' => 'e',
        '/Ĝ|Ğ|Ġ|Ģ/' => 'G',
        '/ĝ|ğ|ġ|ģ/' => 'g',
        '/Ĥ|Ħ/' => 'H',
        '/ĥ|ħ/' => 'h',
        '/Ì|Í|Î|Ï|Ĩ|Ī|Ĭ|Ǐ|Į|İ/' => 'I',
        '/ì|í|î|ï|ĩ|ī|ĭ|ǐ|į|ı/' => 'i',
        '/Ĵ/' => 'J',
        '/ĵ/' => 'j',
        '/Ķ/' => 'K',
        '/ķ/' => 'k',
        '/Ĺ|Ļ|Ľ|Ŀ|Ł/' => 'L',
        '/ĺ|ļ|ľ|ŀ|ł/' => 'l',
        '/Ñ|Ń|Ņ|Ň/' => 'N',
        '/ñ|ń|ņ|ň|ŉ/' => 'n',
        '/Ò|Ó|Ô|Õ|Ō|Ŏ|Ǒ|Ő|Ơ|Ø|Ǿ/' => 'O',
        '/ò|ó|ô|õ|ō|ŏ|ǒ|ő|ơ|ø|ǿ|º/' => 'o',
        '/Ŕ|Ŗ|Ř/' => 'R',
        '/ŕ|ŗ|ř/' => 'r',
        '/Ś|Ŝ|Ş|Ș|Š/' => 'S',
        '/ś|ŝ|ş|ș|š|ſ/' => 's',
        '/Ţ|Ț|Ť|Ŧ/' => 'T',
        '/ţ|ț|ť|ŧ/' => 't',
        '/Ù|Ú|Û|Ũ|Ū|Ŭ|Ů|Ű|Ų|Ư|Ǔ|Ǖ|Ǘ|Ǚ|Ǜ/' => 'U',
        '/ù|ú|û|ũ|ū|ŭ|ů|ű|ų|ư|ǔ|ǖ|ǘ|ǚ|ǜ/' => 'u',
        '/Ý|Ÿ|Ŷ/' => 'Y',
        '/ý|ÿ|ŷ/' => 'y',
        '/Ŵ/' => 'W',
        '/ŵ/' => 'w',
        '/Ź|Ż|Ž/' => 'Z',
        '/ź|ż|ž/' => 'z',
        '/Æ|Ǽ/' => 'AE',
        '/ß/' => 'ss',
        '/Ĳ/' => 'IJ',
        '/ĳ/' => 'ij',
        '/Œ/' => 'OE',
        '/ƒ/' => 'f'
    );
    $quotedReplacement = preg_quote($separator, '/');
    $merge = array(
        '/[^\s\p{Zs}\p{Ll}\p{Lm}\p{Lo}\p{Lt}\p{Lu}\p{Nd}]/mu' => ' ',
        '/[\s\p{Zs}]+/mu' => $separator,
        sprintf('/^[%s]+|[%s]+$/', $quotedReplacement, $quotedReplacement) => '',
    );
    $map = $_transliteration + $merge;
    unset($_transliteration);
    return preg_replace(array_keys($map), array_values($map), $string);
}
```

Comment: Please post some relevant code

Comment: I Edited the Post and added the code with the error ^^

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have Fixed The Problem , Have Replace this method with another

```
'method' => function ($string, $separator = '-') {
    if (is_null($string)) {
        return "";
    }

    // Remove spaces from the beginning and from the end of the string
    $string = trim($string);

    // Lower case everything
    // using mb_strtolower() function is important for non-Latin UTF-8 string | more info: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php
    $string = mb_strtolower($string, "UTF-8");;

    // Make alphanumeric (removes all other characters)
    // this makes the string safe especially when used as a part of a URL
    // this keeps latin characters and arabic charactrs as well
    $string = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_\s\-ءاأإآؤئبتثجحخدذرزسشصضطظعغفقكلمنهويةى]#u/", "", $string);

    // Remove multiple dashes or whitespaces
    $string = preg_replace("/[\s-]+/", " ", $string);

    // Convert whitespaces and underscore to the given separator
    $string = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", $separator, $string);

    return $string;
},
```

its Working now Thanks ^^

Answer (score 2):

if You Want url arabic like This domain.com/category/معدات-وادوات

```
private function my_slug($string, $separator = '-')
{
    $string = trim($string);
    $string = mb_strtolower($string, 'UTF-8');

    // Remove multiple dashes or whitespaces or underscores
    $string = preg_replace("/[\s-_]+/", ' ', $string) ;
    // Convert whitespaces and underscore to the given separator
    $string = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", $separator, $string);

   return rawurldecode($string);
}
```